# Highlight child view inside Expandable ListView

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I need to highlight the child view of an expandable list view when the user touch an item. I want the color to stay, not just provide a visual feedback. I was able to achieve this with:

```
expandablelistview_options.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) { 
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But my problem is that if I choose another child in the same parent view, the previous selection doesn't get unhighlighted.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is follow this approach:

1) Save the reference or position of the latest item clicked as an int or object.

2) Then you can make a function like this and call it on item click and pass the position:

```
int lastItem = 0;

public void highlight(int clickedItem){
clickedItem.setBackground(//highlight color);
lastItem.setBackground(//unhighlight color);
lastItem = clickedItem;
}
```

3) This will help you to save the reference and will make it easy to handle last and current item. This is just an approach I use while handling cases like this. You have to use this kind of approach for the same.

Hope this helps.